# how to fixed heigth of mat-cell and set it overflow?

Tags: css, angular, mat-table

I created a mat table with a column like this:

```
<div class='table-container mat-elevation-z8'>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

<!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="summary">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Summary </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHTML]  ='element.summary'></td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and i type the css like this:

```
.mat-row{
    white-space:nowrap;
  height:48px;
  max-height:48px;
    overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
    text-overflow: hidden;
}
.mat-cell{
  white-space:nowrap;
  height:48px;
  max-height:48px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  text-overflow: hidden;
}
```

But the height and the overflow didnt work, the row height still auto growth by the body:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR3C3.png]

I did try the ::ng-deep and !important but still not working

How can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

As `td` property is table cell which is not `block` so you cant make it scroll the alternate solution is you need to wrap your info inside some `div` with `overflow :auto` and place it inside `td` then div can scroll

like in your `.ts`

HTML

```
<div class='data-wrap'>
Some data
</div>
```

CSS

```
.data-wrap{
  white-space:nowrap;
  height:48px;
  max-height:48px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  text-overflow: hidden;
}
```